# TextBox validation in asp.net C# for first 2 characters as "Character" only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a validation in text box that when i enter some value in text box, the first two characters should be characters only, followed by 5 int's, then a hyphen and then two int's. E.g : EM12345-23.  Can i achieve such validation at aspx level only.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can. Use a [Regex Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.validators.regexvalidator.aspx).

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="txtCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Code"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{5}-\d{2}$">  
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: can you provide me a link for the same.?

Comment: There you go, added an example and link to msdn class

Answer (score 4):

User asp RegularExpressionValidator

Here is an example:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="regexp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="regexptest" ValidationGroup="regexptest" ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z]{2}.+$">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use a Regex expression. That can be written as

```
string regex = ^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}-\d{2}$
```

This will cause the first 2 characters only to be capital letters. If you want them to be anything them use

```
string regex = ^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{5}-\d{2}$
```

Validate your input.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(regex);
bool result = regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text);

if(result)
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //Failed
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm...I am from Winforms background and hence suggested a different approach compared to others.